# zend dojo forms when layout is disabled

Tags: zend-form, zend-form-element

I want use zend dojo form in pop up, now pop page has layout disabled. Is there a way to get that form working in popup

Answer (score 0):

I created another layout specially for my pop forms and assigned that layout to view via controller. And enabled dojo in that layout.